# How much about extend the Quota for YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There are only 10000 Quota YouTube Data API provide. It is completely to upload video. How much about the fee about extend quota. I didn't see the fee list from API reference. Once other watch our live, does it cost quota?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fee for extending quota just apply for it.

I recommend using the [Query calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) for determining how much quota you will need

The cost is based upon the calls you make to the API so how much it will cost will depend upon how your application works and what calls you are making

[image]